# Xamarin memory leak using Infragistics ScatterLineSeries

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, memory-leaks, xamarin.android, infragistics

**Is there a workaround for the memory leak bug when using ScatterLineSeries in a Xamarin Forms mobile app?**

There is a current memory leak when using infragistics on a xamarin forms app. I have an open case with them but have not heard of a workaround from them.

Since this object is internal to a third party library, what options do I have to forcefully dispose of these objects.

When using live data on a ScatterLineSeries the `Infragistics.Portable.Point" objects are not being disposed of correctly. Using Xamarin Profiler I was able to catch the issue:
[image]

I use an ObservableCollection of chart data points to plot on the infragistics chart. 
This is an existing bug with infragistics but I want to know if anyone has experienced this or has a workaround for this memory leak bug.

**I have tried:**

Setting empty set of points to my ObservableCollection object in the viewmodel but the Infragistics.Portable.Point is created internally when I bind the ObservableCollection to the XamChartData.ScatterLineSeries DataSource in the view.

The viewmodel is not a singleton and does not have strong references to other objects.

Navigating away from the page settles memory usage but once I navigate back the memory allocation reverts to what it had previously been.

With Xamarin Profiler I was able to see the instances of my view model where the ObservableCollection is created and updated. The instance is disposed of on navigating away from the chart page but when I go back the memory usage ramps back up to where it was previously while on the chart page.

Comment: Have you tried assigning an empty set of points to it and check what happens?

Comment: I don't have access to the Points objects. I create an observableCollection that I use for the DataSource for the infragistics XamChartData for the view. I've tried assigning empty sets to the observable collection I have in the viewmodel but it still shows signs of memory leak.